# How to pipe pino-pretty with tsx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, command-line-interface, pino

I installed pino-pretty and tsx in my project and created a command:

`"start": "tsx watch -r dotenv/config ./src/index.ts | pino-pretty",`

Unfortunately I don't get any formatting with this command. Any idea how to make this work instead? I am using Windows but I think that should still work the same. In my code I log using pino:

```js
import { pino } from "pino"

const logger = pino({ name: "test" })
logger.info("hello")
```

Comment: Try using `>`. That's the pipe operator for Windows